# Undefined offset 0 error in php

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I have the following code in of the functions of my controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Cardetail');
      $car_info_oneway= $this->Cardetail->query("Select * from cardetails as c INNER JOIN sellers as s ON c.seller_id=s.id where c.id='$car_id_oneway'");
```

What I want to do is to read value of one of the columns of the result set in my view. However, every time I get an error "Undefined offset 0." Here is the part of my code in view. :

```
$count = $car_info_oneway[0]['c']['total_number_of_seats'];
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Check what `$car_info_oneway` contains like this `print_r($car_info_oneway);`

Comment: it contains an array based on the result returned by the query above.

Comment: How do you know that? Have you tried to dumping out the contents of `$car_info_oneway`. If would suspect that this is the line that contains the error `$count = $car_info_oneway[0]['c']['total_number_of_seats'];` and this is because you try to access an index that does **not** exist. You should also add the code for your controllers `query()` method.

Comment: yes, I get this error when I try to print the value in that variable "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Well then perhaps your array does not have numeric keys or it might be empty. Like I said try using `print_r($car_info_oneway);` or `var_dump($car_info_oneway);` to see how the data is structured.

Comment: I just now tried print_r(@car_info_oneway) : The output is Array(). With var_dump the output is array(0){}

Comment: Yes, and that means that the array is empty and you get the error because you're trying to access an index of `0` which does **not** exist. In other words something is wrong with your query or perhaps in your `query()` method.

Comment: ohhh...I did check it before as well. However, I executed the same query in the database directly and checked. It  does return the data. I'll have to check what is the issue while reading it. Thanks..

Comment: In that case I would validate that `$car_id_oneway` is really set before calling `query()` and I would also enable `error_reporting()` (like one **should** do while developing) to get a better error description.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake by me.. Before this I was writing the car_id_oneway in the Cookie and over here I was reading it. It was a spelling mistake while writing the cookie that created this whole issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `query()`? You should be using Cake's `find()` method to retrieve your data using `contain` to retrieve the Seller data too (you need to make sure your `Cardetail` and `Seller` models are correctly associated).

I assume you're just trying to retrieve a single `Cardetail` record so should be using `find('first')`:-

```
$this->loadModel('Cardetail');
$car_info_oneway = $this->Cardetail->find('first', [
    'contain' => ['Seller'],
    'conditions' => [
        'Cardetail.id' => $car_id_oneway
    ]
]);
```

When using `find('first')` the returned array will not be numerically indexed so your `$count` will be:-

```
$count = $car_info_oneway['Cardetail']['total_number_of_seats'];
```

If you run in to issues you can check the returned array using `debug($car_info_oneway)`.